# Change start Activity in Espresso Test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I do not know how to change start activity in Espresso test.

First activity in application is SplashActivity. Activity which I want to test is DepartmentsActivity.

That is my test file:

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DepartmentsActivityTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<DepartmentsActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<DepartmentsActivity>(DepartmentsActivity.class) {
    @Override
    protected Intent getActivityIntent(){
        Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                .getTargetContext();
        return new Intent(targetContext, DepartmentsActivity.class);
    }
};

@Test
public void departmentsActivityTest() throws InterruptedException {

    onView(allOf(withText(getResString(R.string.my_departments))))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    onView(childAtPosition(
            childAtPosition(withId(R.id.content_layout), 0), 1))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    onView(allOf(childAtPosition(
                    allOf(withId(R.id.content_layout), childAtPosition(
                                    IsInstanceOf.<View>instanceOf(android.widget.ScrollView.class),
                                    0)), 5)))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}

private static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(
        final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
            parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
            return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                    && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
        }
    };
}

private String getResString(int id) {
    Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    return targetContext.getResources().getString(id);
}
```

}

Whatever I tried, it is always starting with SplashActivity (not DepartmentsActivity).

What else I have tried:

Init ActivityTestRule like this:

```
    @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<DepartmentsActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(DepartmentsActivity.class, true, true);
```

And trying to launch exact activity for exact test:

```
    @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<DepartmentsActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(DepartmentsActivity.class, true, false);

@Test
public void departmentsActivityTest() throws InterruptedException {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    activityRule.launchActivity(intent);
    (...)
}
```

But in every try emulator is always starting with SplashActivity (which is set as launcher activity in manifest). I do not want to change launch activity in manifest.

I am using these espresso versions:

```
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there something in your production code that starts splash activity conditionally? I.e is there something that calls splash activity other than the launcher?

Comment: i think you are running complete test suite , just click on that test and press `ctrl+shift+f10`

Comment: @Be_Negative you had right! We was restarting app to SplashActivity when      backend url is null (url was set on SplashActivity). Thanks, totally forgot about that!